# JavaScript - iterating over a series of questions (array/object)

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this snippet of code a user is supposed to select a word that matches the definition (definition and matching word is stored in an array). Now I've got the functionality of checking whether the selected word is matching the first element of the array. If the right word is selected, a success message gets displayed. At the moment, the user gets asked to click on the word matching the first definition from the array. I'd like to have an option to move to the next one, once the first has been answered correctly. I'll add more words and definitions later.

Here's what I've got:

```
var onA = [
    {t: "grooming", d: "an activity when someone builds an emotional connection with a child to gain their trust for the purposes of sexual abuse or exploitation."},
    {t: "cyberbullying", d: "an activity that involves the use of ICT, particularly mobile phones and the internet, deliberately to upset, threaten and intimidate someone else."}
];

function get_selection() {
    var txt = '';
    var feedback = document.querySelector("#onA .feedback");
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    document.querySelector("#onA .word").innerHTML = txt;

    function feed(oldClass, newClass, message) {
        feedback.classList.remove(oldClass);
        feedback.classList.add(newClass);
        feedback.innerHTML = message.bold();
    }

    if (txt === onA[0].t) {
        feed("alert-warning", "alert-success", "Well done!");
    } else {
        feed("alert-success", "alert-warning", "Try again!");
    }    
}

document.getElementById("onA").onclick = get_selection;
document.querySelector("#onA .def").innerHTML += onA[0].d;
```

Edit: First problem I've got is when I want the get_selection() function to take an argument (eg. an index for the array to be used in the if conditional statement within the function, it stops working:

```
function get_selection(i) {
    var txt = '';
    var feedback = document.querySelector("#onA .feedback");
    if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    document.querySelector("#onA .word").innerHTML = txt;
    function feed(oldClass, newClass, message) {
    feedback.classList.remove(oldClass);
    feedback.classList.add(newClass);
    feedback.innerHTML = message.bold();
    }

    if (txt === onA[i].t) {
    feed("alert-warning", "alert-success", "Well done!");
    } else {
    feed("alert-success", "alert-warning", "Try again!");
    }    
}





document.getElementById("onA").onclick = get_selection(0);


document.querySelector("#onA .def").innerHTML += onA[0].d;
```

It doesn't show any error in the console, just the feedback whether the right/wrong word has been selected does not work any more. 
Thank you.

Comment: which part of the code moves on to the next question?

Comment: once txt === onA[0].t is true, there should be a way  of asking the user to move to the next question and change the onA[0].d from last line to onA[1].d. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: you are supposed to try to solve the problem before asking for help. You current program does not show this effort. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've added the first stumbling block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need to do is have your `get_selection()` function return a function itself. Otherwise, the following line:

```
document.getElementById("onA").onclick = get_selection(0);
```

just runs the function, which returns `undefined` and effectively clears out the `onclick` handler for the `onA` element.

Change your `get_selection` function to the following structure:

```
function create_get_selection_handler(index) {
    return function click_handler() {
        // (rest of code goes here and uses "index" variable)
    };
}
```

Then change the `onclick` line to:

```
document.getElementById("onA").onclick = create_get_selection_handler(0);
```

If you want the technical reason why this works, look up how *closures* work in Javascript and why they are awesome (essentially, the inner function has access to the `index` variable in the outer function). The [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures) is a good starting point, and the rest of the page is worth reviewing as well.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I need to study closures as I don't understand the idea behind them. Will try to move forward now with the the next step.

Comment: If this answer helped you with your current specific problem, accept it (click the tick outline). If you have any further questions, you can post them as new questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll start another question.